# Populating a 0 value where there a no rows of delivery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find instances where a there is no delivery and return the value as 0, however because there is 0 delivery, there are no rows of data for that day.

It's a simple query that works in terms of pulling data when there is delivery.

```
select 
  date(timestamp_micros(delivered_on)) as day,
  coalesce(delivery,0) as value
from
  delivery_table
```

what I'm hoping for is something along these lines:

```
**day      |value**

8/10/19  |123

8/11/19  |456

8/12/19  |0
```

---

what my actual result is:

```
**day      |value**

8/10/19  |123

8/11/19  |456
```

Comment: You will need to create a temporary table with a list of dates and `LEFT JOIN` that to your `delivery_table`, otherwise, you can't get a row in the results set if there's no corresponding row to select from.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a calendar table which stores all dates which you want to appear in your report.  Something like this:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2019-08-10' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-11' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-12'
)

SELECT
    d.dt,
    COALECSE(t.value, 0) AS value
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN delivery_table t
    ON d.dt = t.day;
```

In practice, you probably would not use a CTE as the calendar table, but would instead either generate a date sequence, or maybe just create a bona fide table containing the actual dates.

Comment: Seems to be a very inefficient way to generate a table of dates. I would `DECLARE` a temporary int and loop through an `INSERT INTO dates DATEADD(day, @Startdate, @DateIndex)` (Actual code will depend on the RDMS of course).

Comment: @daShier I only used a CTE to simplify the explanation of my query.  As I already stated, there are better ways to generate a calendar table in BigQuery (or any other version of SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Use `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY()`:

```
SELECT dte, COALECSE(t.value, 0) AS value
FROM unnest(generate_date_array(date('2019-08-10'), date('2019-08-12'))) dte LEFT JOIN
     delivery_table t
     ON d.dt = t.day;
```